# executable jar file not running due to unable to start embedded tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I am working on a web app and I am so close to finishing but am stuck here.This is a spring boot application , its my api. Its a maven project. I have tried looking for answers all over and cant seem to figure this out. this is the error im getting.

```
org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:17) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:265) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:196) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1066) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: C:\Users\Saheb\Desktop\src\main\resources\bootsecurity.p12 (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1063) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Saheb\Desktop\src\main\resources\bootsecurity.p12 (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.getResource(CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.java:117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:283) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
        ... 28 common frames omitted

2020-06-08 21:38:24.103  INFO 6340 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

I cant figure out the issue, someone mentioned that i should try changing my java sdk to java 8 and i did that and it still wont work. I dont know what else to do.

here is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Saheb\Desktop\src\main\resources\bootsecurity.p12 (The system cannot find the path specified)` exist file?

Comment: yes that file exists @sh.seo

Comment: @sh.seo oh wait that file should have existed in the project not in the desktop... why is it looking there???

Comment: check server.ssl.key-store in application.yml(or properties)

Comment: @sh.seo yea that seems to be it! now if i change this and move the ssl cert to src/main/java and change the path there, will it get packaged there alltogether?

Comment: yes. spring boot' jar has all files in resources directory.

Comment: @sh.seo I tried moving bootsecurity.p12 into the src/main/java folder and set the keystore to /src/main/java but when I run the exec java it looks for a folder outside the package named /src/main/java

Comment: There is no `src/main/resource` (where it should be) as that is the root of the classpath. Remove that part from your path in the `application.properties` it should just have the name of the file/